# MySQL - Get Total numbers found in three different fields (College Work)

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET('67', numbers_line1) > 0 THEN 1 
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET('80', numbers_line1) > 0 THEN 1 
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET('47', numbers_line1) > 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS total_numbers_line_1,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET('67', numbers_line2) > 0 THEN 1 
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET('80', numbers_line2) > 0 THEN 1
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET('47', numbers_line2) > 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS total_numbers_line_2,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET('67', numbers_line3) > 0 THEN 1 
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET('80', numbers_line3) > 0 THEN 1
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET('47', numbers_line3) > 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS total_numbers_line_3
FROM cards
where id_bingo = '5bgd8moawmkh5'
GROUP BY
    id_card
HAVING
    total_numbers_line_1 > 0
    OR total_numbers_line_2 > 0
    OR total_numbers_line_3 > 0;
```

What I need is that, in addition to returning the tickets that have the drawn numbers, it still brings three other variables, namely "total_numbers_line_x", which will be the total number of numbers found in each line of the ticket (my tickets have three lines of five numbers each, totaling 15 numbers). These variables (total_numbers_line_x) will be used to find out if the player won the court, corner or full ticket.

The current sql query, brings the value "1", if the numbers are found, regardless of the number of numbers found, in short, it is not adding the amount, just returning the value "1" because of the "THEN" clause

I already tried other approaches, other ways of writing the SQL query, I tried using ChatGPT, but even it couldn't help me with that (probably in this case I didn't succeed in writing the correct prompt)

Comment: Sample input, expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each number shouldn't be in the same `CASE` expression, since it will only use one of them. They should be in separate conditions that you add together.

```
    SUM(IF(FIND_IN_SET('67', numbers_line1), 1 ,0) +
        IF(FIND_IN_SET('80', numbers_line1), 1, 0) +
        IF(FIND_IN_SET('47', numbers_line1), 1, 0)
    ) AS total_numbers_line_1,
```

It would be better if you didn't use comma-separated lists in the first place. Normalize the schema so each is in a separate row, then you should be able to use normal `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` with a condition like `WHERE number IN ('67', '80', '47')`

Comment: Thanks bro, thank you very much, it worked 100%, you saved my life bro kkkkk

Comment: How i can order the results using "number_lines_x" and DESC clausule? I tried use GREATEST, IF and When and not work, MySQL dont support Aliases in this clausules,

Comment: You should be able to use aliases in ORDER BY.